# Stop Servicestack from logging all Get Set commands

Tags: servicestack, servicestack.redis

Since I upgraded Servicestack a few days ago it has started logging all my Redis requests with a logger named ServiceStack.Redis.RedisNativeClient.

```
S: GET urn:iauthsession:2nzuknVSZf0kChC0HmT9
R: $-1
S: GET urn:iauthsession:2nzuknVSZf0kChC0HmT9
R: $-1
S: GET urn:iauthsession:2nzuknVSZf0kChC0HmT9
R: $-1
```

Its fairly filling up my logs. Is there a way to disable this? Is it related to the servicestack upgrade? or have I inadvertently set a configuration setting? (I haven't knowingly been near Redis code).  We did also get upgraded on Azure to a newer version of Redis - would this have caused it?  (seems unlikely)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can disable verbose logging in Redis with:

```
 RedisConfig.DisableVerboseLogging = true;
```

Otherwise you can just turn off DEBUG logging in your Logging provider, e.g:

```
LogManager.LogFactory = new ConsoleLogFactory(debugEnabled:false);
```